# NODE and SQL Server : transaction commit and rollback

Tags: node.js, sql-server, reactjs, express

I'm trying to insert an array of data into a table and this has to be done in a single go. I'm trying to implement a transaction with SQL Server in node js.

I can insert the data successfully, but the issue is whenever there is an error, the transaction is still getting committed. I know my code is not correct, can anyone help me correct my code?

```
saveStockbulkDetails = async(requestBody, res) => {
  var toggle = true;
  let dDate = new Date();
  let currentDate = moment(dDate).format("YYYY-MM-DD");
  const transaction = new sql.Transaction(dbconn1);
   transaction.begin((err) => {
    const request = new sql.Request(dbconn1);
    
   for (let i = 0; i < requestBody.pipeDetails.length; i++) {
      console.log(requestBody.pipeDetails[i].heat);
      request.query(
        "insert into JSULLCStockDB.dbo.ma_smallpipe_shipping_details(jsuordref, itemno, pipeid, heat, loadtallyno, uid_ent, tmstp_ent, date_ent)" +
          " values('" +
          requestBody.jsuOrder +
          "'," +
          "'" +
          requestBody.itemNo +
          "'," +
          "'" +
          requestBody.pipeDetails[i].pipeid +
          "'," +
          "'" +
          requestBody.pipeDetails[i].heat +
          "'," +
          "'" +
          requestBody.loadTallyNo +
          "'," +
          "'" +
          requestBody.uid_ent +
          "'," +
          "getDate()," +
          "'" +
          currentDate +
          "')",
        (err, res) => {
          if (err) {
          transaction.rollback((err) => {
        console.log("transaction commit rollback");
      });
          }
        }
      );
    }
    console.log(toggle);
    if (toggle) {
      transaction.commit((err) => {
        if (err) {
          console.log("transaction commit error!!");
        } else {
          console.log("transaction commit success!!");
        }
      });
    } 
  });
}
```

Comment: You really should be using [Prepared Statements](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mssql#prepared-statement) with parameters instead of constructing a statement with tainted user inputs. The code you've got currently is wide open to SQL Injection Attacks so at some point you might encounter [Little Bobby Tables](https://xkcd.com/327/).

Comment: Er, `toggle` is always true?? And yeah, this has SQL injection all over it

Comment: I know there is an issue, but i need to insert a bulk data with transaction, while there is an error with transaction, still half of the data which is inserted is not getting deleted